# Can I create an alias for WHERE conditions in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to find all the companies that have employees matching certain criteria, and return information about those employees, and also about the owners of those companies. My SQL is a bit repetitive, though, and I'm wondering if there's a way to use an alias for some of my WHERE conditions.

Consider this query:

```
SELECT json_agg(employee.*) employees_and_admins, company.*
    FROM company
    JOIN employee ON employee.company_id = company.id
    WHERE employee.owner IS TRUE
        -- This is where the repetitive stuff starts
        OR employee.first_name IS NULL
        OR employee.last_name IS NULL
        OR employee.date_of_birth IS NULL
        OR employee.hire_date IS NULL
        OR employee.email IS NULL
    GROUP BY company.id
    HAVING sum(CASE
        -- Note the repetition; note also we're not checking employee.owner here
        WHEN (
            employee.first_name IS NULL
            OR employee.last_name IS NULL
            OR employee.date_of_birth IS NULL
            OR employee.hire_date IS NULL
            OR employee.email IS NULL)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Is there some way to avoid repeating all those OR conditions? It has been a bit heard to search for answers online because I keep getting information about SELECT aliases.

Comment: Short answer, NO. Long answer. Are different conditions for different subqueries, so you have to define it on each one.

Comment: And there is nothing wrong with repeating it

Comment: Then only I can think is create a function to receive all parameter and return boolean. But doesnt really simplify much the code.

Comment: My only worry with repeating is the standard worry about duplicative code - update in one place and not the other, have problems. But at least the two instances are part of the same query, where it should be harder to make that sort of mistake.

Comment: I can live with it if there isn't a way to do it. Mostly just wanted to know if there were a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lateral` and the convenient [`bool_or`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select json_agg(employee.*) employees_and_admins, company.*
from
    company
    inner join
    employee on employee.company_id = company.id
    cross join lateral (
        select
            employee.first_name is null
            or employee.last_name is null
            or employee.date_of_birth is null
            or employee.hire_date is null
            or employee.email is null
            as any_null
    ) cjl
where employee.owner or any_null
group by company.id
having bool_or(any_null)
```

The alternative to lateral is nested queries.

Comment: An elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for better readability (this practically will not affect performance), e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION has_a_null_value(e employee)
RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
    SELECT
        e.first_name IS NULL
        OR e.last_name IS NULL
        OR e.date_of_birth IS NULL
        OR e.hire_date IS NULL
        OR e.email IS NULL
$$;

SELECT json_agg(employee.*) employees_and_admins, company.*
    FROM company
    JOIN employee ON employee.company_id = company.id
    WHERE employee.owner OR has_a_null_value(employee)
    GROUP BY company.id
    HAVING sum(has_a_null_value(employee)::int) > 0;
```

Comment: I guess you need to define employee type? And can you point me how is `has_a_null_value(employee)` send a row instead of the table?

Comment: The type `employee` already exists. The function gets a row as an argument.

Comment: What you mean already exists? Just creating a table employee also create the type? Im must be missing something here

Comment: Yes, the type is automatically created.